# Compose UI tests has a long delay when finished

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have just setup a UI test for Jetpack Compose. It takes 46s~ to finish the test. With breakpoints, I can see that it instantly checks for the code I have written, which is good. The weird part is, is that it takes another 45s~ for the test to be marked as completed. In the meantime, nothing is logged or happening, what can I do?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@LargeTest
class EmojiReactionTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    fun listGoesOverTheFold() {
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText(LocalizedText.SHARE_MY_LOCATION).assertIsNotDisplayed()
    }
}
```

Comment: Any setup and cleanup in the tests?

Comment: @Abhimanyu Nope, this is literally my code, nothing more

Comment: Having the same issue. Any solutions so far ?
I found that it happens when I test the composables from my Launcher activity

Comment: @EdharKhimich Yes, I updated my mac to the newest version as well as Android Studio. Since then I had to issues anymore

Comment: Which Android Studio and Mac OS version are you using ?

Comment: @EdharKhimich 14.0 (23A344) and Giraffe 2023.3.1. I had a type in my previous comment where 'to' had to be 'no' but I think you figured it out already :)

Comment: @J.Doe Thank you 
I have 14.2 and Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 
Will switch to Giraffe now